# File size limits in file upload using multer

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, multer

I'm implementing a file uploader that accepts various file types, including images and videos. I need to manage the maximum file sizes differently for images and videos: images should have a maximum size of 10MB, while videos should be limited to 100MB. I'm looking to accomplish this functionality using a single instance of Multer, a middleware for handling multipart/form-data.

```
import path from "path";
import { TEMP_DIRECTORY_PATH } from "../constants.js";
import { ApiError } from "../utils/ApiError.js";

const storage = multer.diskStorage({
    destination: function (req, file, cb) {
        cb(null, TEMP_DIRECTORY_PATH);
    },
    filename: function (req, file, cb) {
        const fileName = Date.now() + "-" + Math.round(Math.random() * 1e9);
        const fileExtension = path.extname(file.originalname);
        cb(null, fileName + fileExtension);
    },
});

const fileFilter = (req, file, cb) => {
    const imageMimeTypes = [
        "image/png",
        "image/jpeg",
        "image/webp",
        "image/svg+xml",
    ];
    const videoMimeTypes = ["video/mp4", "video/webm"];

    const allowedMimeTypesForFields = {
        avatar: imageMimeTypes,
        coverImage: imageMimeTypes,
        videoFile: videoMimeTypes,
        thumbnail: imageMimeTypes,
        featuredImage: imageMimeTypes,
    };

    const allowedMimeTypesForField = allowedMimeTypesForFields[file.fieldname];

    if (!allowedMimeTypesForField) {
        return cb(
            new ApiError(
                500,
                `Invalid field ${file.fieldname}. Please ensure you are uploading to a valid field.`
            ),
            false
        );
    }

    if (allowedMimeTypesForField.includes(file.mimetype)) {
        cb(null, true);
    } else {
        cb(
            new ApiError(
                400,
                `Invalid file type for ${file.fieldname}. Allowed file types for ${file.fieldname} are ${allowedMimeTypesForField.map((type) => type.split("/")[1]).join(", ")}.`
            ),
            false
        );
    }
};

export const upload = multer({
    storage,
    fileFilter,
});
```

Is it possible to do this with my given code. Or I have to make 2 multer instances one for image and one for video.

Comment: You can't get `file.size` there

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need `fileFilter` function because we can get `file.size` there  so we can simply convert this into middleware.

Refer this [issue](https://github.com/expressjs/multer/issues/186) in multer.

In the middleware you can apply the file size validation like below.

```
function FileValidationMiddleware(req,_,next){
    const { files } = req;
    
    const types = {
        'image': {
            maxSize: 10 ,//MB
            mimetype: [
                "image/png",
                "image/jpeg",
                "image/webp",
                "image/svg+xml",
            ]
        },
        'video': {
            maxSize: 100, //MB
            mimetype: [
                "video/mp4", 
                "video/webm"
            ]
        }
    }

    const allowedMimeTypesForFields = {
        avatar: 'image',
        coverImage: 'image',
        videoFile: 'video',
        thumbnail: 'image',
        featuredImage: 'image',
    };

    Object.values(files).forEach(([file]) => {
        const fileSize = file.size / 1024 / 1024; // in MB

        const allowedMimeTypesForField = allowedMimeTypesForFields[file.fieldname];
    
        if (!allowedMimeTypesForField) {
            throw new ApiError(
                500,
                `Invalid field ${file.fieldname}. Please ensure you are uploading to a valid field.`
            );
        }
    
    
        if (types[allowedMimeTypesForField].mimetype.includes(file.mimetype)) {
            if(fileSize > types[allowedMimeTypesForField].maxSize){
                throw new ApiError(400,`Invalid file size for ${file.fieldname}. Allowed maximum file size is ${types[allowedMimeTypesForField].maxSize} MB`);
            }
        } else {
            throw new ApiError(
                400,
                `Invalid file type for ${file.fieldname}. Allowed file types for ${file.fieldname} are ${types[allowedMimeTypesForField].mimetype.map((type) => type.split("/")[1]).join(", ")}.`
            );
        }
    });

    next();

}
```

Comment: router.route("/register").post(
    upload.fields([
        { name: "avatar", maxCount: 1 },
        { name: "videoFile", maxCount: 1 },
    ]),
    FileValidationMiddleware,
    registerUser
);
how this works for this type of routes? one more thing there is not file in req, there is files in req and you cannot access file.size in this way

Comment: I have forget about files, let me change that for multiple files

Comment: @BhomikRanjan I have made some modifications to do that, Please verify

Comment: It's working fine in my server

Comment: no, there is a mistake in the code (in else block)

Comment: throw new ApiError(
                400,
                `Invalid file type for ${fieldname}. Allowed file types for ${fieldname} are ${types[allowedMimeTypesForField].mimetype.map((type) => type.split("/")[1]).join(", ")}.`
            );      this should be the code of else block

Comment: Its already in the else block @BhomikRanjan

Comment: you are writting directly allowedMimeTypesForField.map which is wrong and gives error. But thanks for help

Comment: These are some typo mistakes, just change to `types[allowedMimeTypesForField].mimetype.map`